# Programming interface

Tags: programming-languages

I currently building a data collection system [mainly "EFM" - enterprise feed back management] using .NET.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to provide the user to script and manipulate the objects -> like a programming language but with minor functionalities

For example - "Confirmit" or "Survey Gizmo" both these tools have controls as well as a scripting language to control the flow and logic of the programs

Thanks

Comment: Check out IronPython, IronRuby, and/or the DLR. Might help.

Comment: thanks for the comment - may be my question is not pretty clear.

I want my user to program and manipulate the objects accordingly in my online application.

Comment: A specific example would help. A generic answer to your question would be "Have well defined exit points/extension points where the user is allowed to modify the behaviour. To simplify end user programming, create a DSL. The languages mentioned by Martinho could be used to create a simple DSL tailored to your needs".

Comment: @user309010: As an very hands-on example of using the DLR and dynamic languages to achieve this, look at this video from the PDC: http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT30

Comment: For example - "Confirmit" or "Survey Gizmo" both these tools have controls as well as a scripting language to control the flow and logic of the programs

Comment: the video was very helpful....

Comment: my question has been rephrased

Answer (score 0):

[Lua](http://lua.org/) is designed to provide scripting capabilities to applications written in C.  There is a Lua.NET which supports .NET.  Lua is clearly powerful enough to enable your user to "program and manipulate the objects" in your online application.  Lua may be overkill; I'm finding it hard to tell from your question.